# Problem with homer in findMotifs.pl when using input and bg fasta

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta, motif

I am using the following command:

```
findMotifs.pl input.fa fasta ./Output -fastaBg bg.fa -len 8,10,12 -norevopp
```

The input and bg fasta have this structure and the bg fasta include all sequences in input plus many others:

```
>ENSMUST00000027125_Coq10b_mmu_chr1_55071635_55072702_+_utr_55071803_55072702(+)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Selected Options:
    Input file = input.fa
    Promoter Set = fasta
    Output Directory = ./CPEB4
    Will use FASTA files for motif finding
        Target Sequences = input.fa
        Background Sequences = bg.fa
    Motif length set at 8, 10, 12, 
    Will not search the reverse strand
    Using custom gene IDs for GO analysis
    Parsing FASTA format files...

    Progress: Step4 - removing redundant promoters

    Progress: Step5 - adjusting background sequences for GC/CpG content...

    Sequences processed:
        0 total

    Frequency Bins: 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8
    Freq    Bin Count
Illegal division by zero at /software/HOMER/bin/assignGeneWeights.pl line 63.

    Normalizing lower order oligos using homer2

    Reading input files...
    0 total sequences read
    Autonormalization: 1-mers (4 total)
        A   inf%    inf%    -nan
        C   inf%    inf%    -nan
        G   inf%    inf%    -nan
        T   inf%    inf%    -nan
    Autonormalization: 2-mers (16 total)
        AA  inf%    inf%    -nan
        CA  inf%    inf%    -nan
        GA  inf%    inf%    -nan
        TA  inf%    inf%    -nan
        AC  inf%    inf%    -nan
        CC  inf%    inf%    -nan
        GC  inf%    inf%    -nan
        TC  inf%    inf%    -nan
        AG  inf%    inf%    -nan
        CG  inf%    inf%    -nan
        GG  inf%    inf%    -nan
        TG  inf%    inf%    -nan
        AT  inf%    inf%    -nan
        CT  inf%    inf%    -nan
        GT  inf%    inf%    -nan
        TT  inf%    inf%    -nan
    Autonormalization: 3-mers (64 total)
    Normalization weights can be found in file: ./CPEB4/seq.autonorm.tsv
    Converging on autonormalization solution:
    ...............................................................................
    Final normalization:    Autonormalization: 1-mers (4 total)
        A   inf%    inf%    -nan
        C   inf%    inf%    -nan
        G   inf%    inf%    -nan
        T   inf%    inf%    -nan
    Autonormalization: 2-mers (16 total)
        AA  inf%    inf%    -nan
        CA  inf%    inf%    -nan
        GA  inf%    inf%    -nan
        TA  inf%    inf%    -nan
        AC  inf%    inf%    -nan
        CC  inf%    inf%    -nan
        GC  inf%    inf%    -nan
        TC  inf%    inf%    -nan
        AG  inf%    inf%    -nan
        CG  inf%    inf%    -nan
        GG  inf%    inf%    -nan
        TG  inf%    inf%    -nan
        AT  inf%    inf%    -nan
        CT  inf%    inf%    -nan
        GT  inf%    inf%    -nan
        TT  inf%    inf%    -nan
    Autonormalization: 3-mers (64 total)

    Progress: Step6 - Gene Ontology Enrichment Analysis
    Skipping...

    Progress: Step7 - Known motif enrichment

    Reading input files...
    0 total sequences read
    1006 motifs loaded
    Cache length = 11180
    Using hypergeometric scoring
    Checking enrichment of 1006 motif(s)
    |0%                                    50%                                  100%|
    =================================================================================
Illegal division by zero at /software/HOMER/bin/findKnownMotifs.pl line 152.

    Progress: Step8 - De novo motif finding (HOMER)

    Scanning input files...
!!! Something is wrong... are you sure you chose the right length for motif finding?
!!! i.e. also check your sequence file!!!

    Scanning input files...
!!! Something is wrong... are you sure you chose the right length for motif finding?
!!! i.e. also check your sequence file!!!

    -blen automatically set to 2
    Scanning input files...
!!! Something is wrong... are you sure you chose the right length for motif finding?
!!! i.e. also check your sequence file!!!
Use of uninitialized value in numeric gt (>) at /software/HOMER/bin/compareMotifs.pl line 1394.
    !!! Filtered out all motifs!!!
    Job finished
```

Comment: If you do not quickly get an answer you need here on Stack Overflow, try posting the question on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/).

Comment: `  Sequences processed: 0 total` Is your fasta file malformed?